# Apache Drill handling cp1252 character codes

Tags: encoding, apache-drill

The data that we are querying as part of the csv holds cp1252 character codes and apache drill gives below error:

org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 Fragment 0:0 [Error Id: 53bc07e3-a6e4-4301-a858-205be382275e on 172.16.243.116:31010] (java.lang.RuntimeException) java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 org.apache.drill.exec.expr.fn.impl.CharSequenceWrapper.decodeUT8():185 org.apache.drill.exec.expr.fn.impl.CharSequenceWrapper.setBuffer():119 org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.FiltererGen174.doEval():50 org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.FiltererGen174.filterBatchNoSV():100 org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.FiltererGen174.filterBatch():73 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.filter.FilterRecordBatch.doWork():81 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractSingleRecordBatch.innerNext():93 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():162 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():119 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():109 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractSingleRecordBatch.innerNext():51 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.limit.LimitRecordBatch.innerNext():115 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():162 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():119 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():109 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractSingleRecordBatch.innerNext():51 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.svremover.RemovingRecordBatch.innerNext():93 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():162 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():119 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():109 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractSingleRecordBatch.innerNext():51 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.project.ProjectRecordBatch.innerNext():135 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():162 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.BaseRootExec.next():104 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ScreenCreator$ScreenRoot.innerNext():81 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.BaseRootExec.next():94 org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor$1.run():232 org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor$1.run():226 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged():-2 javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs():422 org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs():1657 org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.run():226 org.apache.drill.common.SelfCleaningRunnable.run():38 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker():1142 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run():617 java.lang.Thread.run():745 Caused By (java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException) Input length = 1 java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException():281 org.apache.drill.exec.expr.fn.impl.CharSequenceWrapper.decodeUT8():183 org.apache.drill.exec.expr.fn.impl.CharSequenceWrapper.setBuffer():119 org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.FiltererGen174.doEval():50 org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.FiltererGen174.filterBatchNoSV():100 org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.FiltererGen174.filterBatch():73 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.filter.FilterRecordBatch.doWork():81 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractSingleRecordBatch.innerNext():93 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():162 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():119 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():109 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractSingleRecordBatch.innerNext():51 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.limit.LimitRecordBatch.innerNext():115 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():162 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():119 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():109 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractSingleRecordBatch.innerNext():51 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.svremover.RemovingRecordBatch.innerNext():93 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():162 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():119 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():109 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractSingleRecordBatch.innerNext():51 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.project.ProjectRecordBatch.innerNext():135 org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():162 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.BaseRootExec.next():104 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ScreenCreator$ScreenRoot.innerNext():81 org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.BaseRootExec.next():94 org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor$1.run():232 org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor$1.run():226 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged():-2 javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs():422 org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs():1657 org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.run():226 org.apache.drill.common.SelfCleaningRunnable.run():38 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker():1142 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run():617 java.lang.Thread.run():745

Is there are way to handle such data in Apache Drill?

Comment: When i query a text that has cp1252 encoded characters, there is no problem. as an example, command : select columns[0] from myHDFS.testdata.`/stack_43372025.txt`, output: 'TEST SÆK'. Could you give us some details of your query, please.

Comment: My query is on top of a csv file : SELECT columns[0],columns[1],columns[2] FROM dfs.`tmp.Sales.csv`;

Comment: I was not able to find a way in Apache Drill to handle cp1252 encoding but used the iconv utility to convert them to utf8 encoding

iconv -f cp1252 -t utf8 inputfile.csv > outputfile.csv

Apache Drill was able to query the data effectively then.

Please update if anyone is able to handle it directly from Apache Drill.

Answer (score 0):

@OP
I know this is an old post, how ever I ran into this challenge last week with new data feed.
Directly in Apache Drill (MapR version), I used STRING_BINARY() to convert the cp1252 set.
Not the elegant or efficient solution, but it works.

apache drill 1.10.0
"drill baby drill"
0: jdbc:drill:zk=titana-ch2-p3:5181/drill/TIT> use sys;
+-------+----------------------------------+
|  ok   |             summary              |
+-------+----------------------------------+
| true  | Default schema changed to [sys]  |
+-------+----------------------------------+
1 row selected (0.975 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:zk=titana-ch2-p3:5181/drill/TIT> select version from version;
+----------+
| version  |
+----------+
| 1.10.0   |
+----------+
1 row selected (0.409 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:zk=titana-ch2-p3:5181/drill/TIT>
0: jdbc:drill:zk=titana-ch2-p3:5181/drill/TIT> select * from users.`sbalas002c`.drill_spl_char;
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| ORIG_CAMPAIGN_LINE_ID  |                   ORIG_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME                    |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 30092278               | 1573256-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup�_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_SSEA  |
| 30092282               | 1573257-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup�_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_WORD  |
| 30092286               | 1573254-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup�_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_BLIS  |
| 30092290               | 1573255-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup�_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_NSEA  |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows selected (0.445 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:zk=titana-ch2-p3:5181/drill/TIT>
0: jdbc:drill:zk=titana-ch2-p3:5181/drill/TIT> select ORIG_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME,
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> substr(ORIG_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME,1,4) sub_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> from users.`sbalas002c`.drill_spl_char;
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: DrillRuntimeException: Unexpected byte 0xa0 at position 36 encountered while decoding UTF8 string.

Fragment 0:0

[Error Id: 1889163a-f847-48ad-a7a9-bbe4284e112c on titand-ch2-p20.cable.comcast.com:31010] (state=,code=0)
0: jdbc:drill:zk=titana-ch2-p3:5181/drill/TIT>
0: jdbc:drill:zk=titana-ch2-p3:5181/drill/TIT> select ORIG_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME,
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .>  STRING_BINARY(ORIG_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME) SB_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME,
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .>  regexp_replace(STRING_BINARY(ORIG_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME),'\\xA0','') Good_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> from users.`sbalas002c`.drill_spl_char;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                   ORIG_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME                    |                      SB_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME                      |                   Good_CAMPAIGN_LINE_NAME                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1573256-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup�_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_SSEA  | 1573256-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup\xA0_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_SSEA  | 1573256-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_SSEA  |
| 1573257-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup�_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_WORD  | 1573257-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup\xA0_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_WORD  | 1573257-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_WORD  |
| 1573254-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup�_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_BLIS  | 1573254-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup\xA0_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_BLIS  | 1573254-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_BLIS  |
| 1573255-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup�_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_NSEA  | 1573255-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup\xA0_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_NSEA  | 1573255-1_306774_SeattleTheatreGroup_201901_ISV_SEA_Z_NSEA  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows selected (0.64 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:zk=titana-ch2-p3:5181/drill/TIT>

Hope this helps others.